# Formatting multidimensional arrays

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy, multidimensional-array

How can I code a function that isolates the `0`s and `1`s in the 2 dimensional array. So the function is to separate the bits into chunks.

```
[[     0  38846]
 [     1  51599]
 [     0  51599]
 [     1  52598]
 [     0 290480]
 [     0 360467]]
```

Expected Output:

```
Ones = 51599 ,52598
Zeroes = 38846, 51599, 290480, 360467
```

Comment: The subject line tells us nothing about what you are trying to do.  You aren't making an array.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I am following. Are you looking for a particular method, like with numpy or is list comprehension good enough? In any case, here are some examples:

```
x = array([[     0,  38846],
           [     1,  51599],
           [     0,  51599],
           [     1,  52598],
           [     0, 290480],
           [     0, 360467]])

#List comprehension
ones  = [v for b,v in x if b]
zeros = [v for b,v in x if b==0]

#Numpy access
ones  = x[x[:,0]==1][:,1]
zeros = x[x[:,0]==0][:,1]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code should do the trick:

```
arr = np.array([[0, 38846],
                [1, 51599],
                [0, 51599],
                [1, 52598],
                [0, 290480],
                [0, 360467]])
col1 = arr[:, 0]
col2 = arr[:, 1]
zeros = col2[col1 == 0]
ones = col2[col1 == 1]
```

The lines

```
col1 = arr[:, 0]
col2 = arr[:, 1]
```

get the 1st column (containing the `0`s and `1`s) and the 2nd column (which contain the numbers you want).

The `col1 == 0` creates an array of booleans for which indexes where `col1` is `0` are `True` and the other indexes are `False`. By doing `col2[col1 == 0]`, we can then get the values in column 2 where the corresponding index of `col1 == 0` is true, which gives us the values in column 2 which correspond to `0`s in column 1.